# TopMost Form from dll library

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on .NET Class Library Assembly called Provider. Provider is loaded by Host application via Reflection. Provider implements:

```
interface ISomeService 
{
    ShowPopup(PopupParms params);
}
```

One of the Provider's feature is to display WinForms Form. It must be done in separate Thread so that Provider doesn't block the Host application. To launch WinForm I create another Thread and from it I call:

```
Application.Run(ApplicationContext)
```

Where ApplicationContext class is:

```
 public class PopupFormContext : ApplicationContext
    {

        public PopupFormContext(PopupParameters param, ILogger logger)
        {
            var popupForm = new PopupForm(param);
            popupForm.Closed += (sender, args) =>
                           {
                              logger.WriteInfo("PopupForm closed.");
                              ExitThread();
                           };
            popupForm.ShowDialog(); //Tested also with Show();

        }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work but I can't force the popup window to be TopMost. The result is that for some cases when Host launch

```
ISomeService.ShowPopup();
```

the form displays in minimized state and user could possibly miss it. Of course The TopMost property is set to true. I've made some tests with timer which set WindowState=FormWindowState.Normal each few seconds but it doesn't look as good solution.

Comment: Taming a bunch of UI code you cannot control rarely comes to a good end.  Work with the vendor or author of this DLL to get somewhere.

Comment: Try to require the 'Owner' of the dialog to be sent as part of PopupParms so that you will launch the dialog with the ShowDialog(Owner) overload.